# How to close QWebEnginePage (Python)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage, qwebengine

I am using `QWebEnginePage`s as tabs in my `QWebEngineView` and my question is how to properly close the `QWebEnginePage`? I can't find any solution, I searched in Stackoverflow, Google, Qt docs and some other sites.

Comment: "As tabs"? Do you mean that you use only one view and always change the page? Why?

Comment: So I should replace them with views instead of pages?

Comment: Yeah, I partially rewrote the code to replace `QWebEnginePage` with `QWebEngineView` and it works fine now.